# deploying a contract from geth

Tags: go-ethereum, solc

Hi I have been trying to deploy a contract from geth console to the testnet, I established a connection and also mined to make sure its all working... one thing I couldn't do for some reason is use solc in my geth console, whenever I try to compile inside the console I get the error:

> solc: exit status 1
>   
> Must provide a file

I couldn't figure it out so if anyone may have solved it or encountered it I would be greatful!

Another thing is that when I try to deploy a compiled solidity contract (compiled in an online service) i keep getting the same result

```
console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + 
    ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
```

Why is there no address here? and no transaction hash?

Anyway thanks for anyone who may help!

Comment: Can you provide the full commands you used to compile?

Comment: I get the same error. I believe something is wrong with my install of solc. why the checkmark though? I doubt this fixes your problem.

Comment: i actually dont know how it was checkmarked 0_o i still have a problem with deploying this contract... the commands i used are first creating the vars for the contract and then i just copy the web3 deploy contract and paste it into the command line... if i want to compile on my command line it just wont work

Comment: As you've been able to deploy, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the following:

- first, the account you are deploying the contract from in **geth** is
  unlocked when making the deployment transaction

In the geth console run:

```
personal.unlock("0x12345...", "password", "timeout in ms");
```

- check if the respective account has sufficient balance to deploy the
  transaction. You can get the balance of each account by calling
  **checkAllBalances()** defined [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#checking-account-balances)

The fact that there is no transaction hash can mean the following:

- the transaction was made but not confirmed
- an insufficient gas exception has occurred and the transaction was
  not mined

Comment: the problem really was the unlocking of my account thank you!